# naming convention for keys in toml file

Tags: naming-conventions, toml

looking at [toml](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) repo, I don't see any restriction/suggestion on naming convention for keys

looks like most of the variables are `lowercase` but wanted to know what's the best practice -naming convention- for keys?

let's say I want to have a key called `firstname` which one is better?

`firstname`

`first_name`

`first-name`

`firstName`

`FirstName`

Answer (score 4):

Standard is `underscore_naming`. It isn't documented, but most .toml files use that.